# How can i position my numbers one under another?

Tags: html, css

I have the following table

```css
table td {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.red {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">$ 11.122,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">$ 11.1,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">$ 11.122,00232</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="red">$ 11.122,00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

i need to have my numbers centered in the `td` it self, but i can't find a way to position the numbers one under another so the end result in the table will be the same if i will do

```
table td {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

but on this way i am just moving the numbers on the right and they are one unmder another. But i need them `centered` with the numbers one under another

Comment: For future reference, it can be very helpful to include a quick mockup image that demonstrates the result you are attempting to achieve, even if it's a rough approximation (as long as it gets the point across). As-is, the description was a little confusing and could have been interpreted at least a couple of different ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest your text in a `flex` layout structure and then set a `min-width` that is equal to your widest content. For example, something like this:

```html
<td class="red">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">$ 11.122,00</div>
  </div>
</td>
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

---

If this is the result you're after, here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3s2gfpz/).

[image]

---

Or if you're trying to do something like this, here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0y6cgkq/).

[image]

Comment: But the content is not centered - `$ 11.122,00` the first row is not looking like it is in the center

Comment: Can you add a mock-up image of what you’re after?